# how to substitute strings in a set of files with different strings?

Tags: shell-script, bioinformatics

I have a set of vcf files, each one has a string started with 'SRR'.e.g., in file1 I have the following line:

```
#CHROM  POS ID  REF ALT QUAL    FILTER  INFO    FORMAT  SRR2481146_1
```

In file2, I have:

```
 #CHROM POS ID  REF ALT QUAL    FILTER  INFO    FORMAT  SRR2481151_1
```

In file 3, I have:

```
 #CHROM POS ID  REF ALT QUAL    FILTER  INFO    FORMAT  SRR2481163_1
```

And I want to replace these strings with specific cell line names, e.g., replace 'SRR2481146_1' in file1 with 'HCT116_DMSO', replace 'SRR2481151_1' in file2 with 'SW_DMSO', replace 'SRR2481163_1' in file3 with 'COLO205'and so on.

i.e., for file1, the desired output should be :

```
 #CHROM POS ID  REF ALT QUAL    FILTER  INFO    FORMAT  HCT116_DMSO
```

And for file2:

```
 #CHROM POS ID  REF ALT QUAL    FILTER  INFO    FORMAT  SW_DMSO
```

I knew that I could do that individually using code like the following:

```
sed -i 's/SRR2481146_1/HCT116_DMSO/g' file1
sed -i 's/SRR2481151_1/SW_DMSO/g' file2
```

But since I have ~100 files, doing that would be too time-consuming.

Is there any good way?

Thanks!

Comment: Please, [don't post images of text](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4086/psa-please-dont-post-images-of-text).

Comment: You have a VCF file. The strings, I assume, does not only occur in the VCF header, but could also occur in the annotated variations.  You should post a _text_ example of the places where the strings may occur, so that people that does not know about the VCF format may have a chance to help you.  Also, you may want to ask _real_ bioinformaticians at https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/ as they know of VCF parsers and bioinfo tools that could possibly be used.

Comment: Sorry @Kusalananda, I just replaced the image

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Kusalananda wrote this is better asked on https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/ . Maybe someone can move this question to there?

Create a text file where in each line you write the old name and the desired new name delimited by a whitespace.

```
$ cat names.txt
SRR2481146_1 HCT116_DMSO
SRR2481151_1 SW_DMSO
```

Use [bcftools reheader](http://www.htslib.org/doc/bcftools.html#reheader) to change the sample names like this:

```
$ bcftools reheader -s names.txt file.vcf > file_renamed.vcf
```

You can use [gnu parallel](https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/) to run this command on all `vcf` files in a folder:

```
$ parallel 'bcftools reheader -s names.txt {} > {.}_renamed.vcf' ::: *.vcf
```

Comment: Thanks very much, @finswimmer! This is exactly what I am looking for. I will try your method.

Comment: @JuanXie If you're happy with the answer, upvote it.  If it is solving your issue, [accepting it](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) would be the best way of saying "Thank You!"  Accepting an answer
also indicates to _future_ readers that the answer actually solved the problem.

Comment: Hi finswimmer ! I tried bcftools on individual files and it worked well, yet for the parallel style I typed exactly the same code you showed but it didn't work. Is there anything that I need to change to make it work ? Thanks!

Comment: I used a for loop with bcftools and it worked, just curious about the parallel

Comment: What do you mean by "didn't work"? You can use the `--dryrun` parameter for parallel to see how the commands will look like.